# No data output on website after insert a prepare statement for SQL injection

Tags: php, mysql, database, prepared-statement

This was the code before and it worked

```
<?php
    include ("connect.php"); // $conn

    $sql = "SELECT name, date, adress, number FROM event ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 4";    
    
    foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){
        
        $date = date('j.n.Y');
        $actDate = strtotime($date);
        //echo $date;                               Ausgabe aktuelles Datum im deutschen Format
        //echo $actDate;                            Ausgabe des Datums als Zahl
    
        $dbDate = $row['date'];
        $eventDate = strtotime($dbDate);
        //echo $dbDate;                             Ausgabe des Datums der Veranstaltung
        //echo $eventDate;                          Veranstaltungsdatum als Zahl
    
        if ($actDate <= $eventDate) {                                                    
            // hide entries with lower date 
    
            $originalDate = $row['date'];                                               
            $formatDate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($originalDate));                                               
            // hide entries with lower date 
    
            echo "  

            <tr>
                <td>".$row['name']."</td>
                <td>$formatDate</td>
                <td class='w3-hide-small'>".$row['adress']."  ".$row['number']."</td>               
            </tr>

    
    
            ";
        }
    }
?>
```

Now I have added a prepared statement against SQL injections, and now the new code has no error output but also no data output from DB, I don't know where I can find the error. You can ignore the date format, I don't change there anything, its just the prepare editing which will not work I think.

```
<?php
    include ("connect.php"); // $conn
        
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, date, clock, adress, number, link, info FROM event WHERE (name, date, clock, adress, number, link, info) = (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ORDER BY date ASC");   
    $sql->bind_param("sississ", $name, $date, $clock, $adress, $number, $link, $info);

    $sql->execute();

    $result = $sql->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            
        foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){
                
            $date = date('d.m.Y');
            $actDate = strtotime($date);
            //echo $date;                               Ausgabe aktuelles Datum im deutschen Format
            //echo $actDate;                            Ausgabe des Datums als Zahl
            
            $dbDate     = $row['date'];
            $eventDate  = strtotime($dbDate);
            //echo $dbDate;                             Ausgabe des Datums der Veranstaltung
            //echo $eventDate;                          Veranstaltungsdatum als Zahl
            
            if ($actDate <= $eventDate) {               // Einträge mit abgelaufenem Datum verbergen 
            
            $originalDate = $row['date'];                                               
            $formatDate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($originalDate));
            
            echo "  
                    
                <div class='accordionEvent nav_bottom w3-container w3-center'><h4>".$row['name']." am $formatDate ab ".$row['clock']."</h4></div>
                <div class='panel head'>
                    <p>Adresse: ".$row['adress']." ".$row['number']."</p>
                            
                        
                    <p>Link: <a href=".$row['link']." target='_blank'>".$row['link']."</a></p> 
                            
                            
                    <p>".$row['info']."</p>
                </div>
                <br>
                    
                ";
            }
        }       
    }   
    $sql->close();  
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I think the first code examle was the correct one. I never heard of fixed SQL statements with fixed params being used for SQL injections. Where to inject? there are no params.

Comment: The WHERE part is normally `WHERE name = ? AND  date = ?...`

Comment: i have tried name = ? AND date = ? there is no difference

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin so i dont need to scare about injections with this code?

Comment: @ted bear In general, you always have to be aware of the possibility of SQL injection. Consearning this paticular query as it is, You don't have to, as all the params are fixed. Also see answers below. You have problems in the original code.

Comment: All these `$name, $date, $clock, $adress, $number, $link, $info` are not defined, so propably your query in 2nd snippet is like "select ... where data in every column is null"

Comment: `WHERE (name, date, clock, adress, number, link, info) = (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` I've never seen a multivalued SQL predicate (other than 'IN') Anyone know where I can found out more?

Answer (score 0):

You still have a line of the original code, that breaks the loop:

```
 $result = $sql->get_result();
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){ // <--- 
     // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the same statement. If you have no params you can skip the bind part.

```
<?
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, date, adress, number FROM event ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 4");

$sql->execute();
```

Then remove lines 16

```
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row){
```

and line 51

```
}
```

Currently you are executing the query over and over again and overwriting `$row`
Most likely you do not get an error because `$sql` is a prepared statement and not a string.

Deleting the mentioned lines should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for the answer i tried without these line but same result, no output

Comment: Have you tried to debug the `while` loop? Just put some `var_dump($row)` in there and check if it gets executed. If not check the query manually and see if it returns anything

Comment: By the way your query is completely different in your two examples
1.) SELECT name, date, adress, number FROM event ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 4
2.) SELECT name, date, clock, adress, number, link, info FROM event WHERE (name, date, clock, adress, number, link, info) = (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ORDER BY date ASC
Maybe just the wrong query?

Comment: thanks fo the tipp, var_dump($row) and echo "this is a test "; in the while loop give no return

Comment: Check your SQL statements

Comment: I changed the query cause of the prepare statement, if i dont change he show this error "Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean"

Comment: I edited the answer, if you do not have any parameters you can skip the binding. You only need to bind params if you really have some in your query.
Your query `SELECT name, date, adress, number FROM event ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 4` does not have any so...